# Is an email first sent and then copied to the sent folder, or the other way round?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I sent an email using Yahoo Mail. Their servers are rather slow from time to time and my browser just stood still. Nothing seemed to happen (I did not get the confirmation). So I decided to log out and log back in and try again, because I thought that it did not send. However, when I checked it, the mail was in the "sent folder", so I did not send it again, since I guessed that it was sent. I am not sure though now.

How is the "sent folder" handled? Is it managed on my account specific? Is it possible for an email to land in the "sent folder" without actually being sent? Basically, is an email first sent and than copied to the "sent folder", or first copied to the "sent folder" and than sent?

Comment: You could click on the 'sent' mail and expand the message header to  get details of how it was sent.

Comment: The only thing I can see is the From: and the To: part. I am not sure how to get more details. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The "Sent" folder is a construct of mail clients, and the behavior of it is entirely dependent on what client you're using.

At most a mail server might pre-create a folder named "Sent", but after that the server has nothing to do with it. When you send a message it's up to Outlook/Thunderbird/Eudora/Webmail/etc to put a copy of the message in that folder. At what point a given mail client does that is at the discretion of the people who made it.

Logically it should only be placed there after it has been successfully sent, but I've seen developers do things that fly in the face of logic.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, however, @newuser wants to know how this is handled in Yahoo! (web)mail. Basically, when you say _At what point a given mail client does that is at the discretion of the people who made it_ - yes, how does Yahoo! mail work in this case?

Comment: thanks Sammitch for this answer. Indeed you are right, but as Ramdal pointed out, I am interested if anyone knows how yahoo handles it (the actual site, I am not using a third party software like windows outlook etc. I am just using the actual website mail.yahoo.com). Thank you both for the answer btw. Cheers.